# Integrals of motion remain constant (proof)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals, soliton-theory

How would one proceed with proving that the integrals of motion

$$\text{mass} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\text{torque} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u^2(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\text{energy} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}u^2_x(x,t) - u^3\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$

are constants of motion (remain unchanged) for the Korteweg-De Vries (KdV) equation.

An idea would be straight differentiating with respect to time $t$ and then showing that it's equal to zero, thus meaning they are constant. But how would one carry out this differentiation properly ?

Comment: Well, just differentiate under the integral sign and replace $u_t$ with what the KdV equation says that it should equal. Then play around with integration by parts (assuming that $u \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$). By the way, it's Korteweg, not Kurteweg.

Comment: Page 6 here http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~millerpd/docs/651_Winter18/Topic02-651-W18.pdf seems helpful enough.